# MySQL: how to create a trigger that add not-null constraint?

Tags: mysql

I have created the `customer` table that has a trigger that not allow null value on the `customer_id` column. it looks like:

```
create table customer(
            customer_id varchar(20) UNIQUE,
            customer_name varchar(15) NOT NULL,
            password varchar(10) NOT NULL,
            social_number varchar(14) not null,
            phone_number varchar(13) NOT NULL,
            email varchar(30) NOT NULL,
            address varchar(50) NOT NULL,
            primary key ( social_number )
);
```

But, creating the following trigger causes this error.

```
create trigger null_checker 
on customer 
after insert 
as 
delete from customer 
where customer_id is null;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'on customer after insert as delete from customer where customer_id is null' at line 1
```

What's wrong with? I could add not-null constraint using `not null` specifier. but I am not allowed to do it because creating the trigger is a part of my assignment. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why do you stick to the trigger? Add the NOT NULL constraint to the field, and the DBE will solve the problem by preventing the insertation of NULL values

Comment: as a side note when trigger is executed on a table you can not run another query to insert/delete/update within the trigger on the same table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use right syntax:

```
create trigger null_checker 
after insert  on customer 
for each row
   delete from customer 
   where customer_id is null;
```

But you **cannot modify** the same table from trigger.

A solution, without triggers, may be is change the `sql_mode` to avoid null values defined in your columns.

```
set sql_mode = 'TRADITIONAL';
```

That command says to MySQL “give an error instead of a warning” when inserting an incorrect value into a column, like inserting NULL to a 'NOT NULL column.

More info: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sql-mode.html

Comment: you said the syntax you give is right, but gives a error when I use that trigger?

Comment: Yes, because you can't modify (update/delete) the same table from their own trigger.

Comment: The proposed solution dones not use triggers, but changes the sql mode  to prevent null insertions. You will need add NOT NULL to customer_id field.